# Archive dropdown styling not applied

Tags: php, css, javascript, archives, dropdown

I am trying to add a custom dropdown for archives but struggling with couple of mistakes that might be the reason why it doesn’t work.

The CSS only gives my dropdown the `width`, not the other styles included for it. I am pretty sure the issue is about PHP. I can’t attach option values to more than just the first choice. How can I fix that?

#### PHP

```
<select id="cd-dropdown" name="cd-dropdown" class="cd-select"                   onChange='document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;'>
<option value="-1"><?php echo attribute_escape(__('Select Month')); ?></option>
<?php wp_get_archives('type=monthly&format=option&show_post_count=1'); ?> </select>
```

#### CSS

```
.cd-dropdown > span,
.cd-dropdown ul li:nth-last-child(-n+3) span {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
```

I think the problem is about values. I am trying to style my dropdown the way Codrops teaches: [here](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/11/29/simple-effects-for-drop-down-lists/). Right now I don’t get any style at all to my dropdown, except the `width` that is set to `300`.

Answer (score 1):

You're targeting cd-dropdown with a class indicator (the period), the cd-dropdown is an ID and should therefore be targeted with the ID selector (a hashtag).

```
#cd-dropdown > span,
#cd-dropdown ul li:nth-last-child(-n+3) span {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
```